# Check if Database Exists Before Creating

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, t-sql

This seems pretty trivial, but it is now frustrating me.

I am using C# with SQL Server 2005 Express.

I am using the following code. I want to check if a database exists before creating it. However, the integer returned is -1 and this is how MSDN defines what ExecuteNonQuery() will return as well. Right now, the database does exist but it still returns -1. Having said that, how can I make this work to get the desired result?

```
private static void checkInventoryDatabaseExists(ref SqlConnection tmpConn, ref bool databaseExists)
{
    string sqlCreateDBQuery;
    try
    {
        tmpConn = new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes");

        sqlCreateDBQuery = "SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases where name = 
        \'INVENTORY\'";

        using (tmpConn)
        {
            tmpConn.Open();
            tmpConn.ChangeDatabase("master");

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateDBQuery, tmpConn))
            {
                int exists = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (exists <= 0)
                    databaseExists = false;
                else
                    databaseExists = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }

}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As of SQL Server 2005, the old-style `sysobjects` and `sysdatabases` and those catalog views have been deprecated. Do this instead - use the `sys.` schema - views like `sys.databases`

```
private static bool CheckDatabaseExists(SqlConnection tmpConn, string databaseName)
{
    string sqlCreateDBQuery;
    bool result = false;

    try
    {
        tmpConn = new SqlConnection("server=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes");

        sqlCreateDBQuery = string.Format("SELECT database_id FROM sys.databases WHERE Name 
        = '{0}'", databaseName);

        using (tmpConn)
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateDBQuery, tmpConn))
            {
                tmpConn.Open();

                object resultObj = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();

                int databaseID = 0;    

                if (resultObj != null)
                {
                    int.TryParse(resultObj.ToString(), out databaseID);
                }

                tmpConn.Close();

                result = (databaseID > 0);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This will work with any database name you pass in as a parameter, and it will return a bool true = database exists, false = database does not exist (or error happened).

Comment: trying it now.. executescalar returns object so you have to cast before assignment.

Comment: It throws an exception of "Invalid Column Name 'INVENTORY'"

Comment: sorry, yes - the database name needs to be in single quotes - updated my answer

Comment: This works great.. if it does not exist, it throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." otherwise it returns a non-zero database id!

Comment: Just wondering why you can't use `DB_ID` here?  Less error-prone, no?  (Looks like someone else submitted that - I'm curious if there was a reason you chose this way instead)

Comment: @Aaronaught: No particular reason - I guess I'm just more used to querying the sys.* catalog views to find out this kind of stuff....

Comment: I wonder that this connection string is generic? Does it need to be changed any situations? or it works always?

Comment: This would be better if you selected a count and checked the return > 0, rather than using an error exception.

Comment: If the database doesn't exist your scalar will cause an exception:
int databaseID = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();

You could either check for a null return from the scalar, or change the SELECT database_id  to something like SELECT count(*).

Comment: @TappaTappa: the problem wasn't the call to SQL Server - but if the database doesn't exist, `null` is returned from `ExecuteScalar()` and I was just casting that to an int without checking for `null` - added that code and now it works just fine - no exception is thrown, even for a database that doesn't exist

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm saying. I did it the other way and used your original code except I changed the SELECT database_id to a SELECT count(*).

Comment: I am getting this error while running the query in pgadmin. ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Answer (score 44):

Reading this a few years on and there's a cleaner way of expressing this:

```
public static bool CheckDatabaseExists(string connectionString, string databaseName)
{
      using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      {
           using (var command = new SqlCommand($"SELECT db_id('{databaseName}')", connection))
           {
                connection.Open();
                return (command.ExecuteScalar() != DBNull.Value);
           }
      }
}
```

Comment: be wary of sql injection here, use parameterized queries instead of string interpolation

Comment: but db_id is SQL Server T-SQL function so I cant see any problem with sql injection here. ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This seems to be time consuming

Comment: One thing I found is that the connection string you use here can't specify the database you're checking. If you do, then `connection.Open()` will throw an exception if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8):

shouldn't this

```
"SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases where name = \'INVENTORY\'"
```

be this?

```
"SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases where name = 'INVENTORY'"
```

Also According to MSDN

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

You are doing a SELECT not an DML statement. Why don't you use a ExecuteReader method instead?

Comment: I would use ExecuteReader  instead since you are not doing DML anyway

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to querying the system views is to use the function db_id which returns the Id of the database if it exists, otherwise null. Example T-SQL below:

```
if (db_id('INVENTORY') is null)
begin
    return 0
end
else
begin
    return 1
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Took Stephen Lloyd's code and added some async and sql injection mitigation.

```
public static async Task<bool> TestDatabase(string connectionString, string databaseName)
{
   using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT db_id(@databaseName)", connection))
   {
       command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("databaseName", databaseName));

       connection.Open();

       return (await command.ExecuteScalarAsync() != DBNull.Value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Does Open have an async overload?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) because it will always return -1 for SELECT, as the MSDN link shows.

You'll have to use process a resultset eg `SELECT DB_ID('INVENTORY') AS DatabaseID` or use a variable/parameter: `SELECT @DatabaseID = DB_ID('INVENTORY')`

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of searchers, if you are using Entity Framework, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696588(v=vs.113).aspx) will work:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataModel())
{
    dbExists = System.Data.Entity.Database.Exists(ctx.Database.Connection);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Assembly: `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects` => NuGet

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

var dbExists = new Server(serverOrInstanceName).Databases.Contains(dataBaseName);
```