# SqlPackage.exe ignores its CreateNewDatabase property?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

In VS 2013, have two SSDT composite projects that target the same database:

- The 1st project is responsible for the target database itself.
- The 2nd project has a database reference to the 1st project and is responsible for test data in the target database.

When I deploy the 2nd project, I *only* want to update the target database as needed, *never* drop/create it.

To deploy the 2nd project, I am attempting to use [`SqlPackage.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) as follows to generate a deployment script:

```
C:\some\directory\ssdt\sqlpackage.exe ^
    /a:Script ^
    /op:".\BlahTest.sql" ^
    /sf:".\BlahTest.dacpac" ^
    /tsn:"localhost" ^
    /tdn:"BlahTest" ^
    /p:CreateNewDatabase="False" ^
    REM ...
```

I expected `/p:CreateNewDatabase="False"` to mean that I would not find `DROP DATABASE` or `CREATE DATABASE` in `BlahTest.sql`; but I see the following irrespective of the `CreateNewDatabase` property (i.e. set to `"False"`, set to `"True"`, or omitted):

```
USE [master];


GO

IF (DB_ID(N'$(DatabaseName)') IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)];
END

GO
PRINT N'Creating $(DatabaseName)...'
GO
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ON 
    PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
    LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
GO
```

How can I get `SqlPackage.exe` to output a script that does not drop/create the target database?

Comment: Are you able to do this in a Publish profile? I have one of my profiles set to always create the database (a "new" profile) and all of the others set to not do that. I haven't used the straight command-line too often, but wondering if you need the double-quotes for "False" in order for it to work.

Comment: @PeterSchott: Good question.  Yes, I am able to (not) drop/create as I need when I publish with the profiles I have in the VS projects - just not in the script output by `SqlPackage.exe` for the 2nd project.

Answer (score 2):

The CreateNewDatabase flag just determines whether to always do a full drop and recreate when publishing - perhaps the [SqlPackage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) documentation isn't clear enough about this? It states that CreateNewDatabase "Specifies whether the target database should be updated or whether it should be dropped and re-created when you publish to a database." The assumption is that if you're choosing to publish, you want the database to be created no matter what.

You can't do what you want using just SqlPackage.exe but it would be very easy to write your own code to do it. See [this answer on how to check if a database exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232227/check-if-database-exists-before-creating) for sample code checking if a database exists. You could write a powershell script that does this check and calls into SqlPackage.exe if CheckDatabaseExists is true.

Comment: Interesting.  So it seems that `/p:CreateNewDatabase` makes no sense with `/a:Script`.  Thanks for highlighting that subtlety, but what a shame that the option is not applicable to `/a:Script`.

Comment: You can definitely use SQLPackage w/ a publish profile to avoid that. You may not be able to do it w/ a straight command line, but the publish profiles let you generate a script that does not try to drop/recreate the database. If you use the same options and connection regularly, I'd probably look into creating a profile.

Comment: @KevinCunnane: I take that back. `SqlPackage.exe`'s documentation lists `/p:CreateNewDatabase` as a property for `/a:Publish` _and_ `/a:Script`.

Comment: @PeterSchott: Good instincts. `SqlPackage.exe`'s documentation does not list `/Profile: { string }` (or `/pr: { string }`) as a parameter for `/a:Script` in - only for `/a:Publish`. In fact, its documentation is clear that the only valid parameter for `/a:Script` is `/OutputPath: { string }` (or `/op: { string }`).  Strangely, though, `/pr: { string }` _does_ influence `SqlPackage.exe /a:Script`'s behavior - i.e. like using the specified publish profile to generate a script in VS.