# Detect Configure method invoked from migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application and I am seeding the database from the Configure method. The problem is that the method is also called during migration, causing an error since the database is not created yet. There is a way where I can check if the method is called from migration?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    SeedData.EnsureSeedData();
    ...
}
```

Comment: The 2.0 guidance is to move the seed code to Main so that migrations don't run it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you somehow check if database exists? You can probably do it [with something like Database.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696617(v=vs.103).aspx) and just not run seed when it does not exist

Comment: damn, even with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2232379/7104041) ?

Comment: Well, I am using EF Core and I am looking form something clean :-)