# check if database exists or not in asp.net page_load event

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

Hi everyone I want to create a web app in asp.net to upload excel sheet data into a SQL-server database.

I am facing problem in that on page_load event check if database with any name exists in DB if not then create DB and also check table with any name exist in DB if not then create table in database.

Comment: You want to check for any specific databse name and table name? What database server you are using? SQL server, mysql, Oracle?

Comment: i am using sql server

Comment: want to check database 'fleet' is exists or not if not then create it and also check if table name vehicle is exists or not then also create table in database really need a help on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232227/check-if-database-exists-before-creating

Comment: https://bettereducation.com.au/forum/it.aspx?g=posts&t=366

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if Database Exists Before Creating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232227/check-if-database-exists-before-creating)

Answer (score 1):

Uhm I'm pretty sure you can just do:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'database_´name'
```

And it will only create the database if it doesn't already exist.
For the table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name='table_name' AND xtype='U')
CREATE TABLE 'table_name'
```